# multiply defined symbols using static lib

Tags: visual-c++, linker, visual-c++-2010

I have an application that links a static lib both build with visual studio (same version, same machine).

This lib contains multiple c files with mutliple functions (as usual :)

as an example

- lib1.lib

  - file1.c

    - `func_f1_1`
    - `func_f1_2`
  - file2.c

    - `func_f2_1`
    - `func_f2_2`
- prog1.exe

  - (links lib1.lib)
  - main.cpp

    - uses `func_f2_2`
  - strange.c

    - `func_f1_1` (same signature, different definition)
    - `func_f2_1` (same signature, different definition)

lib1 is independently build from prog1.exe

During link time the compiler complains about

```
lib1.lib(file2.obj): error LNK2005: _func_f2_1 already defined in strange.obj
```

The linker does not complain about `func_f1_1`!

I do not fully understand this kind of error since i expected that the linker only grabs symbols from a library that are not defined in the target executable.

It seems to me that the linker tries to put in the content of the whole obj from the lib instead just the function.

Are there any project settings that can i change to get the linker working on a function level? "function level linking" is activated in the compiler properties of both the lib and the program project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your program uses `func_f2_2` then the linker adds the object file `lib1:file2.o` that defines `func_f2_2` to the object list. All symbols in that object file are linked in to the program. This includes all variables that might be used by `func_f2_2` as well as `func_f2_1`.

The linker doesn't complain about `func_f1_1` since there was no reason to load the object file `lib1:file1.o`

If you need to replace `func_f2_1` you have also to add the definition of `func_f2_2` in strange.c.

Comment: does no way exist around this? someone who is more familiar with the gnu toolchain said that this would work on gcc. I allways thought the linking would be done on a symbol level rather than on a file level. especially if function level linking is activated.

Comment: @vlad_tepesch "I allways thought the linking would be done on a symbol level rather than on a file level." -- you always thought incorrectly. "someome said that this would work on gcc" -- it would *not*, unless one uses `-ffunction-sections` command line argument, which makes it behave on function level rather than file level (this is *not* the default behavior, and it is not without cost).

Comment: A good explanation of how the linker works: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/07/09/library-order-in-static-linking

Comment: @Employed The article discusses the operation of GNU ld what is completely different from Microsoft Link, e.g. the order of files is irrelevant and circular dependencies are resolved by the tool.

Comment: @harper You are wrong: the order of files on the link line is just as relevant for Microsoft Link as it is for all other linkers including GNU ld. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcce369f.aspx

Comment: @EmployedRussian Nope, read the article you're referring: " Symbols  ... are searched for ... and then to any libraries at the beginning of the command line." Although the order at the command line affect the preferred search order the behavior is completely different to the GNU ld. GNU ld fails to resolve a symbol when you miss the right order at the command line or group the libraries. Since the OP asked for the lookup of a specific function in a file the difference is important and a wrong description is irrelevant.